# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < results in jQuery countdown timer not functioning

Tags: jquery, timer

Console shows error in title upon page load.

This is the closest JS line around line 102, which is where the console shows the error is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.downCount.js"></script>
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why the error is occurring. I've Googled and searched SO and nothing seems to work.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

**Countdown timer plugin being used** : http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Extremely-Lightweight-jQuery-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-downCount.html

Comment: Can you post the jquery section of the down timer you are using ...

Comment: Please post code in the question. Use the `{}` tool to mark it as code, then it will appear literally in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on the error message, it will take you to the exact line of the error. It's happening on the second line below:

```
$('.countdown').downCount({
<a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/">date</a>: '09/09/2015 12:00:00',
offset: +10
};
```

You can't put HTML in the middle of a Javascript function like that. You're also missing the closing parenthesis for the function call. It should be:

```js
$('.countdown').downCount({
    date: '09/09/2015 12:00:00',
    offset: +10
});
```

```css
ul.countdown {
list-style: none;
margin: 75px 0;
padding: 0;
display: block;
text-align: center;
}
ul.countdown li {
display: inline-block;
}
ul.countdown li span {
font-size: 80px;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 80px;
}
ul.countdown li.seperator {
font-size: 80px;
line-height: 70px;
vertical-align: top;
}
ul.countdown li p {
color: #a7abb1;
font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://hazardousmouse.tv/js/jquery.downCount.js"></script>
<ul class="countdown">
<li> <span class="days">00</span>
<p class="days_ref">days</p>
</li>
<li class="seperator">.</li>
<li> <span class="hours">00</span>
<p class="hours_ref">hours</p>
</li>
<li class="seperator">:</li>
<li> <span class="minutes">00</span>
<p class="minutes_ref">minutes</p>
</li>
<li class="seperator">:</li>
<li> <span class="seconds">00</span>
<p class="seconds_ref">seconds</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! Odd that the plugin creator added that to the code snippet to be pasted. You have been very helpful, kudos.

Comment: The plugin still shows all zeroes for some reason, even though the error is no longer showing up. Any ideas?

Comment: No matter which browser I try it in, it doesn't work... I'm so confused.

Comment: I got lots of other errors from your page, so this isn't the only problem you have.

Comment: I'll be straight - I'm not a JS/jQuery coder. I was just trying to find some 'quick and dirty' stuff that would work. If you wouldn't mind pointing me to where I can begin to clean up/sort out the errors I'd be happy to research the answers myself, I certainly don't expect you to do all the work for me. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you need to hire yourself a programmer. I'm not going to try to debug your website for you here.

Comment: That's fair. One last question though, just to verify - does the countdown timer actually work for you, or does it just show zeroes?

Comment: It works for me. You don't see the countdown when you click on "Run code snippet"?

Comment: It starts at `263.06:44:04`

Comment: It didn't in Chrome but did in Firefox. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Strange. Javascript is enabled in Chrome for me too. Very odd.